# font_scale vs font.size in seaborn rc

Tags: python, seaborn

I have just embarked on Seaborn and encountered some obstacles to get familiar with it. Specifically, with this method:

```
sns.set_context('paper',rc={"font.size":1000,'axes.labelsize':5})
```

What is the meaning of `"font.size"`? I have tried tweaking that parameter several times from `0` to even a huge number as `1000`. Unfortunately, I saw no effects in my experiment.

Comment: `font.size` sets the fontsize of text in the axes. Create some text via `ax.text(0.5, 0.5, "Text")` and use reasonable values, like 12 or 24 for the fontsize.

Comment: Have you had a chance to look at my answer? I can provide more explanation if it's still unclear

Comment: I have tried creating some texts as you instructed and noticed the effects. Thank you very much for your explanation !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `rc` argument of [`seaborn.set_context`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.set_context.html) is passed into [`plotting_context`](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/blob/065d3c1ed58b029d61913cca8fc315cc985ffc91/seaborn/rcmod.py#L335) which [contains](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/blob/065d3c1ed58b029d61913cca8fc315cc985ffc91/seaborn/rcmod.py#L423)

```py
def plotting_context(context=None, font_scale=1, rc=None):
    # ...
    # Now independently scale the fonts
        font_keys = ["axes.labelsize", "axes.titlesize", "legend.fontsize",
                     "xtick.labelsize", "ytick.labelsize", "font.size"]
        font_dict = {k: context_dict[k] * font_scale for k in font_keys}
        context_dict.update(font_dict)
    # ...
```

This piece of code sets the values for text sizing for `axes`, `legend`, `xtick`, and `ytick`. Since those sizes are explicitly set they will ignore the `font.size` parameter, which sets only the default - and is only used if a value has not been explicitly set, as is noted [here](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html#a-sample-matplotlibrc-file)

> ```py
>  ## note that font.size controls default text sizes.  To configure
>  ## special text sizes tick labels, axes, labels, title, etc, see the rc
>  ## settings for axes and ticks [...]
> ```

So in order to see the effects of `'font.size':x` you will need to create some text which is not included in those which have their sizes explicitly set by `plotting_context`, e.g. a [`matplotlib.axes.Axes.Text`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.text.html) instance.